# Error when using linq on datatable

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to run the following code converting my datatable to be usable in linq all seems fines and compiles but when I Execute the statement I get the following statement i get the  error  below new entires just has location and ordernumber in the return values I have to do it this way as I am supporting a legacy access 97 system thanks.

```
 Dim total = From row In newEntries.AsEnumerable()
            Select row.Field(Of Int32)("location") Distinct
    retVal = Convert.ToInt32(total)
```

[image]

This is my whole code but im still getting an invalid type cast error their is data exsits for this order by teh way

```
        Dim retVal As Int32
       Dim newEntries As New DataTable
     Dim script As String = scriptBuilder.GetDistinctOrdersForLocations(OrderNumber)
    newEntries = connection.SqlSelectToDataTable(script)
    Dim total = From row In newEntries.AsEnumerable()
            Select row.Field(Of Int32)("location") Distinct
    retVal = total.Count()
```

Comment: total is an `IEnumerable`, not a single integer value. what is it you want to do?

Comment: @Ric I need to apply that distinct command on the existing data in new entries cause access 97 doenst support distinct count? i just need the value returned from that select row statement

Comment: as the distinct is returning a collection of integer values, you can't convert a collection into an int. the answer below illustrates this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the count of the collection just do this:

`retVal = total.Count()`

this will return the count from the distinct query that you have written.

Just to clarify, @David B identified the data type of location was int16 not int32, so changing this in the linq query resolved the issue.

Comment: its throwing and pecified cast is not valid. on the select row line any ideas budy

Comment: What is the data type of `location`?

Comment: its ms access 97 so its a number be the same same as a int16

Comment: the exception could occur because of the int16 so change it see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query is returning a collection. You should use something like `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

I'm a little rusty on VB LINQ, but try :

```
retVal = Convert.ToInt32(total.First())
```

*Note: This will throw an error if there are no items in the collection.*

Comment: 1980 when i do that I Get speificed cast is not valid is that the exception u sai it woul thrw

Comment: I see now that you wanted the count. Glad you found the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand when you write a LINQ query and assign it to a variable, that variable essentially contains a query *object*, and **not** the results of *running* the query. In order to get the value that results from the query, you need to call some method on the query object such as:

```
total.Single() ' Assumes you expect the query to return exactly one result.
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to int16 worked here is the code for any one else stuck thanks @Ric

```
    Dim retVal As Int32
    Dim newEntries As New DataTable
     Dim script As String = scriptBuilder.GetDistinctOrdersForLocations(OrderNumber)
    newEntries = connection.SqlSelectToDataTable(script)
    Dim total = From row In newEntries.AsEnumerable()
            Select row.Field(Of Int16)("location") Distinct
    retVal = total.Count()
```